# How to update a specific package in MikTex console?

Tags: packages, miktex, update

In MikTex Console (Windows), I go to its Packages tab, and there's no way to search for a package to install, or update an installed package. When I go to the Updates tab, it says that all packages are up to date but I know one is not. How do I update an existing package, let alone re-install a package?

(Similar questions are all about an old version of Miktex)

Comment: the console has two modes (if you installed in multi user mode): user and admin. Check for updates in both. The package list has a search bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching for a package is no problem. Add a filter in the filter tab. Wildcards works. Chose the package you are looking for by clicking the `+`sign and install the package:

[image]

If you want to update a installed package, just run the updater and you will have list of packages that can be updated. Unselect the packages you do *not* want to update, and you will be left with the package(s) you want. (Unfortunately, my system was up to date, but I will updated the picture next time):

[image]

After installing and updating pgf, you access the `patterns.meta` by adding to your preamble, after loading `tikz`:

```
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
```

Thank *John Kormylo* for the tips!

Comment: when i filter for the package called "tikz", 50 names show up containing tikz, but not tikz by itself. i would like to update package tikz so that I have the patterns.meta add-on. none of the 50 names indicate which contains patterns.meta

Comment: tikz is in the pgf package.

Comment: @develarist As Ulrike says: Type in `pgf*` in the filter box and install the pgf-package.

Comment: thanks, pgf and pgfplots I right-clicked on and updated them. They do not resolve my overlying issue with a code I'm trying to run. do you know if patterns.meta is inside pgf and pgfplots? could patterns.meta be, not in tikz stand-alone, but in one of the other 50 tikz names?

Comment: @develarist I do not use tikz, so I have no idea. You may try to ask a new question on how you find patterns.meta for tikz.

Comment: \usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta} after tikz is loaded.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you, I have updated my answer and credited you. I hope this is OK.